# How to validate Base 64 encoded TIFF image in Java

Tags: java, image, validation

I have a Java API through which our customers are uploading Base 64 encoded TIFF image in Java. I want to:

1. Decode the Base 64 string
2. Verify that the file is of TIFF type
3. Image Width = X
4. Image Height = Y
5. Horizontal resolution = xxx dpi
6. Vertical resolution = yyy dpi
7. Bit depth = X
8. Compression type = CCITT T.6
9. Resolution unit = X

Is it possible to achieve all these in Java without using a third-party library and without saving the file to the disk for validation.

I tried implementing them using plain Java. Most of the answers suggested to use third party libraries. I am OK with that, as long as it won't take much time to do all these validations without demanding to save the image to the disk first. This validation has to happen before writing the image into the disk. We want only valid files to be saved in the disk

Comment: Which version of Java?  [Java's `ImageIO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) handles TIFF since Java 9, and [`Base64` has been available since java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html).

Comment: (1)`T6 Compressed Tiff image` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61041199/t6-compressed-tiff-image (2) javadoc TIFFImageWriteParam CCITT T.6 https://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/javadoc/1.1/com/sun/media/imageio/plugins/tiff/TIFFImageWriteParam.html

Comment: For 3-9 I would use a TIFF library. TwelveMonkeys has a low-level TIFF parser, but I am sure also Apache Commons Imaging or Metadata Extractor can be used to access these values.